# Trying to get Typeahead jQuery Plugin to Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to implement Twitter's typeahead plugin into my webpage. I can from the web inspector that the jquery is finding my input with the certain id attribute, however, when I begin typing in the input, the autocomplete functionality is not working. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer finder..." id="typeahead_customer_data" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#typeahead_customer_data").typeahead({
        name: "customer",
        displayKey: "customer",
        prefetch: "/assets/autocomplete/typeahead_customer_data.json",
        limit: 10
      });
    });
</script>
```

**JSON:**

```
["Customer 1","Customer 2","Customer 3","Customer 4","Customer 5","Customer 6","Customer 7","Customer 8","Customer 9","Customer 10"]
```

I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work, but nothing I try will autocomplete when I begin typing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to add `source` instead of `prefetch`. BloodHound Integration also required ... 'source' – The backing data source for suggestions. Expected to be a function with the signature (query, cb). It is expected that the function will compute the suggestion set (i.e. an array of JavaScript objects) for query and then invoke cb with said set. cb can be invoked synchronously or asynchronously. A Bloodhound suggestion engine can be used here, to learn how, see Bloodhound Integration. **Required**. [link](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md)

Comment: You could also try `$('input#typeahead_customer_data').typehead({` selector...